# Create a KStream out of a string passed

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a string\

String input= "{ {"header" : "K"},
{"body" : "Sghd"}}"\

I sent this input to a kafka topic and now I want to consume it as a KStream<String, JsonNode> instead of a String ?\

I tried
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, JsonNode> inputStream = builder.stream(topic);\

but it is not working... Can anyone help me?\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the Serdes for both the classes that you are using. There is a Serdes present for String but an Custom Serdes need to be created for JsonNode. After that you can use this code.

```
KStream<String, Record> inputStream = streamsBuilder
            .stream(topic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), CustomSerdes.JsonNode()));
```

The code that you can use for the serdes is:

```
public class CustomSerdes {
  private CustomSerdes() {}

  public static Serde<JsonNode> JsonNode() {
    JsonSerializer<JsonNode> serializer = new JsonSerializer<>();
    JsonDeserializer<JsonNode> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(JsonNode.class);
    return Serdes.serdeFrom(serializer, deserializer);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but it is showing that KStream and streamBuilder can't be resolved as a type. I included kafka-stream dependency in POM file and tried to import the org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream package, still the same error.....Also tried maven clean...can you tell me how to fix this pls?

Comment: Did you check if you have used the same thing, it is streamBuilder.stream() function which is normally used to make the stream from a topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. i changed the kafka streams version to the latest one